# Removing a post in Wordpress and then reenabling it

Tags: seo, wordpress

Can I take a post down in Wordpress and then repost it? Would this hurt SEO?

Comment: What would be your reasons for taking the post down and will you be posting it to the same URL?

Answer (score 2):

It won't have a huge impact on SEO unless the post has accumlated a lot of incoming links. If so then those links wil be pointing nowhere, and may even be removed the linking website if the post is down long enough, which means you're losing the value those links are giving that page and then that page is distributing throughout your website via internal links.

If that post doesn't have incoming links then removing it and reposting it won't have any noticeable affect on your other pages' rankings or its ranking itself.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options to set the post as a `Draft` or delete the post, then you can always bring it back from the trash. This wont hurt your SEO that much it'll throw a 404 while it's away but once back you'll get your rankings back.